# Populating new column based on unique values

Tags: mysql

I have a list of conversations input by a user:

```
ID    Timestamp    Message
1     12:00:00     "Bird"
1     12:00:05     "Cat"
2     12:00:12     "Dog"
2     12:00:13     "Monkey"
2     12:00:18     "Fish"
2     12:00:22     "Bird"
3     13:50:55     "Fish"
3     13:55:00     "Cat"
3     14:00:00     "Monkey"
3     14:01:14     "Dog"
3     14:01:25     "Bird"
```

I need to create a column that outputs a specific value depending on the user input, partitioned by their unique ID. If any of the users' messages do not include these values, they should be left blank.

Currently this is what I have

```
WITH sub1
AS (
    SELECT t1.id, t1.TIMESTAMP, t1.message
    FROM TABLE t1
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT id,
            LAST_VALUE(message) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY TIMESTAMP) cat_or_dog
        FROM TABLE
        WHERE message LIKE "cat"
            OR message LIKE "dog"
        ) t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
    ),
SELECT TABLE.*, sub1.cat_or_dog 
FROM TABLE 
LEFT JOIN sub1 ON sub1.TIMESTAMP = TABLE.TIMESTAMP
```

Which creates the following table:

```
ID    Timestamp    Message   cat_or_dog
1     12:00:00     "Bird"    "Cat"
1     12:00:05     "Cat"     "Cat"
2     12:00:12     "Dog"     "Dog"
2     12:00:13     "Monkey"  "Dog"
2     12:00:18     "Fish"    "Dog"
2     12:00:22     "Bird"    "Dog"
3     13:50:55     "Fish"    "Dog"
3     13:55:00     "Cat"     "Dog"
3     14:00:00     "Monkey"  "Dog"
3     14:01:14     "Dog"     "Dog"
3     14:01:25     "Bird"    "Dog"
```

This creates a new column, giving either the value "cat" or "dog" partitioned over the ID. The error is for ID 3, where "dog" is the value given for the entire column. I need it to be like below:

```
ID    Timestamp    Message   cat_or_dog
1     12:00:00     "Bird"    "Cat"
1     12:00:05     "Cat"     "Cat"
2     12:00:12     "Dog"     "Dog"
2     12:00:13     "Monkey"  "Dog"
2     12:00:18     "Fish"    "Dog"
2     12:00:22     "Bird"    "Dog"
3     13:50:55     "Fish"    "Cat"
3     13:55:00     "Cat"     "Cat"
3     14:00:00     "Monkey"  "Dog"
3     14:01:14     "Dog"     "Dog"
3     14:01:25     "Bird"    "Dog"
```

Thanks!

Comment: When you say `WHERE query LIKE "cat" OR query LIKE "dog"`, should it be `WHERE LAST_VALUE(message) LIKE...`? IIRC you are looking for the user's messages to contain these values. Can you explain what the Query column represents?

Comment: The query column is the message the user sent. The cat_or_dog column should repeat the value of either cat or dog based on the last value of query before the next cat or dog value for each ID. Sorry if this is confusing, it's my first time posting!

Comment: I realized the column names were not consistent (i changed it a bit from my actual tables), just updated them to be correct

Comment: Why is the first row 'cat', and not, bird (or dog)

Comment: The query I have takes the last value of each ID that is equal to "cat" or "dog" and repeats it for every ID. If the second row did not say "cat" or "dog", the first two rows would be null